# list of Swift arithmetic and comparison operator overloads for numbers?

Tags: xcode, swift, operator-overloading

Is there a place in the documentation or something I can look up dynamically in Xcode 6 that shows all the defined operator overloads for numbers such as the binary arithmetic and comparison operators?

> Swift supports the four standard arithmetic operators for all number types:
>   Addition (+)
>   Subtraction (-)
>   Multiplication (*)
>   Division (/)
>
> Swift supports all standard C comparison operators:
>   Equal to (a == b)
>   Not equal to (a != b)
>   Greater than (a > b)
>   Less than (a < b)
>   Greater than or equal to (a >= b)
>   Less than or equal to (a <= b)

The reason I would like to know is so that I can see when I'll have to use type casting and when I won't because there is a built-in operator overload for two compatible types.

I have a related question on type casting and automatic upscaling, but before I posted it I wanted to make sure I understand the rules Swift defines by default.

Comment: When you command-click on a Swift type ( eg Int ) the you see a (autogenerated) file with all the types, operators, constructors, ...

Comment: I've looked at that, but I don't see the definition that says adding an Int to a Float is legal without a cast (e.g. 1 + 0.8) but you will have to use a cast if one of them is actually a variable or constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin said, you can see a sort of header file that declares these functions by command-clicking Int or some other Swift type. For example the multiplication functions look like this:

```
func *(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8
func *(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
func *(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
func *(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
func *(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64
func *(lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80) -> Float80
func *(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
func *(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64
func *(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
func *(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
func *(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
func *(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16
func *(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
```

All of the arithmetic functions take two numbers of the same type and return a number of that type. That's why you often have to do conversions before arithmetic operations.

You only have to cast variables or constants that already have a type. You can do any arithmetic operation on raw numeric literals.

In this situation both operands are constants and swift gave them a type implicitly when they were defined:

```
let a = 42 //compiler assumes Int
let b = 3.14 //compiler assumes Float
a + Int(b) //returns Int (45)
```

but that doesn't mean having a decimal point will force the literal to be assigned to a Float variable. You can explicitly force the type:

```
var x: Int = 1.1 //shows 1
var y: Float = 1 //shows 1.0
```

That's why you can do stuff like this:

```
var foo = 10
foo + 10.4
```

even though 10.4 is a floating-point literal, because Swift already implicitly typed foo as an Integer it treats the 10.4 literal as an Integer as well and happily adds them together.

Comment: Thanks. Your "foo + 10.4" example leads to my next question about type casting and upscaling, but I feel like that should be its own question, not a "discussion" on this question. Getting a result of 20 of type Int just seems wrong. If the compiler gave a warning that would be one thing, but to simply truncate 10.4 is bad.

Comment: it's kind of weird. c (and likely most c inspired languages) does the same thing. `int x = 0.9;
    printf("%d",x);` prints 0

Comment: also here's the page on literals in swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_879

Comment: "Objective C without the C" ... well, sort of.

Comment: page on Integer and Floating-Point Conversion https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: this is odd `var a = 10;
var b = a + 10.4;  // b = 20`?